# Scala: partitioning number into n almost equal-length ranges

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a function:

```
def NumberPartition(InputNum:Int,outputListSize:Int):List[Range]
```

such that:

```
NumberPartition(8,3)=List(Range(0,3),Range(3,6),Range(6,8))
```

ie. it creates `n-1` equal-length ranges(length=`ceil(InputNum/outputListSize)`) plus the last/first one being slightly smaller.

I want to use this function for agglomeration of an embarrassingly-parallel program consisting of n subroutines that are going to be batch-handled by `n` tasks/threads.

What is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Scala?

I think using Range steps could be helpful:

```
def rangeHeads(n:Int,len:Int):Range=Range(0,n,ceil(n/len))//type conversion for ceil() omitted here.
rangeHeads(8,3)//Range(0, 3, 6)
```

I just need a function that does `(1,2,3,4)->((1,2),(2,3),(3,4))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def roundedUpIntDivide(a:Int,b:Int):Int=a/b + (if(a%b==0) 0 else 1)
def partitionToRanges(n:Int,len:Int): List[(Int, Int)] ={
(Range(0,n,roundedUpIntDivide(n,len)):+n)
.sliding(2)
.map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
.toList
}
```

thanks to @jwvh for suggesting `sliding()`

Comment: One liner? `(Range(0,n,n/len+1):+n).sliding(2).map(x => Range(x(0),x(1))).toList`

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't the exact output you are seeking, perhaps this will be good guidance:

```
scala> def numberPartition(inputNum: Int, outputListSize: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
  (0 to inputNum).toList.grouped(outputListSize).toList
}
numberPartition: numberPartition[](val inputNum: Int,val outputListSize: Int) => List[List[Int]]

scala> numberPartition(8, 3)
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2), List(3, 4, 5), List(6, 7, 8))
```

Comment: Thanks. I really only want a list of tuples consisting of the (head,last) elements of the range, but I figured it would be more readable to output it this way.

Comment: If you want the tuple, then do a map: numberPartition(8, 3).map(list => (list.head, list.last))

Comment: well yeah but I want head and last of my range, not that of your lists. ie. (0,3) not (0,2). I want it to be clean. btw, have a look at the added suggestion. Now I just need to partition `rangeHeads` so that I would have neighboring values paired together.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
def numberPartition(inputNum: Int, outputListSize: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  val range = 0.until(inputNum).by(inputNum/outputListSize + 1).:+(inputNum)
  range.zip(range.tail).toList
}
```

Note:

- `0.until(inputNum)` is an exclusive range `[0, inputNum)`;
- `.by(inputNum/outputListSize + 1)` is the step;
- `.:+(inputNum)` it adds back the range upper bound;
- `range.zip(range.tail)` build couples from list, equals to `.sliding(2).map { case Seq(x,y) => (x,y) }`

Comment: You need to be careful about `inputNum/outputListSize + 1` it gives the right answer if the numbers are not divisible, but the wrong result, if they are. Have a look at `roundedUpIntDivide` in my answer. In general though, your answer is just a more verbose version of the already posted answer, namely: `(Range(0,n,roundedUpIntDivide(n,len)):+n).sliding(2).map(x => (x(0),x(1))).toList`

Comment: The question stated explicitly `length=inputNum/outputListSize + 1` so i just replicated the requested behavior.

Comment: Sure. That needs updating too.